# Is it possible to speed up the process of testing the nservicebus timeout-manager?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, nservicebus

Working on a project where our system uses the nservicebus timeout to trigger an event every 24 hrs. Is it possible, through unit-testing, to "fake" the 24 hrs, so the test can be run at any given time, thus not having to wait for a day before the test will run?

Overridden timeout-method looks like this:

```
public override void Timeout(object state)
{
ExportFileGenerator.GenerateFile(_entryDataStore.GetEntriesOlderThan(DateTime.Now));
RequestUtcTimeout(TimeSpan.FromHours(TimeLeftToDailyJob()), "");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've blogged about how to do this here:

http://www.udidahan.com/2012/02/27/nservicebus-saga-tips/

Answer (score 1):

You simply do that by extracting dependency on time-related services (in your case, that would be `TimeLeftToDoDailyJob` method).

There're basically two ways to achieve that:

- make the method virtual and prepare *testable* version of your class with that method returning some very small (unnoticable) value
- extract that method to brand new class and inject instance of such class as a dependency to your tested class (inversion of control with constructor injection)

I'd go for second approach as it usually forces more decoupled design, which leads to less complex code and as a result - easier tests.